# Signal handling with glade and GTK+

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

Trying to learn Linux development out of curiosity with little knowledge of C.

I am using glade 3.18.3.

I want to create an application in which the text on `label1` will be changed with the input text in `entry1` (input box) when `button1` will be pressed.

I do not know how to pass the needed arguments to the callback.

This is `sample.glade`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Nishant</property>
    <property name="default_width">440</property>
    <property name="default_height">250</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem1">
                        <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem2">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem3">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem4">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem" id="separatormenuitem1">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem5">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Edit</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem6">
                        <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem7">
                        <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem8">
                        <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem9">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem3">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_View</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem4">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Help</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem10">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="name">entry1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button1</property>
            <property name="name">button1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <signal name="activate" handler="on_button1_activate" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkStatusbar" id="statusbar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">10</property>
            <property name="margin_right">10</property>
            <property name="margin_start">10</property>
            <property name="margin_end">10</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="spacing">2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

...and this is `main.c`:

//##gcc -o gladewin main.c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//gchar *buffer1;   //added
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;
  // ## gchar BUFF[100];


    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "sample.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}



//called when button1 is clicked
void on_button1_clicked()
{
//buffer1 = gtk_entry_get_buffer (entry);
//gtk_entry_buffer_get_text (buffer1);

g_print("Button1 pressed");

//gtk_button_set_label (button1 ,"Hi");
//gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(entry1),"hi");   // i think this is correct just need tofigure out what to replace insted of entry1
}
```

Comment: What? the C PreProcessor? Also, there is no c++ anywhere in your code.

Comment: sir, i am using Fedora 22 to test this code. I can sussessfully compile above code using   >>       gcc -o gladewin main.c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic

Comment: Please provide a link to the language C/C++. Until then: C and C++ are different languages. Note that "CPP" is the C preprocessor. It's unlikely you mean that!

Comment: Olaf, I will keep this in mind while asking question next time, thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Look up `gtk_entry_get_text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal callbacks receive specific arguments depending on the type of signal caught. The signature of every callback is [documented](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) by the official documentation.

In glade, when defining a signal, you can pass an additional widget to the signal callback. The real challenge is that you can pass only *one* widget, while you need to have access to both of them (the label and the entry).

In plain C you will stuff the two pointers into one struct and use that instead but if you still want to use glade you must find another solution. A way could be to use two callbacks, e.g.:

[Glade screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4X7K.png)

Then your callbacks could be:

```
void read_from_entry(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkEntry *entry = GTK_ENTRY(user_data);

    g_print("read_from_entry\n");

    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(button), "text", (gpointer) gtk_entry_get_text(entry));
}

void write_to_label(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkLabel *label = GTK_LABEL(user_data);

    g_print("write_to_label\n");

    gtk_label_set_text(label, g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(button), "text"));
}
```

The `g_object_{set,get}_data` pair is used just to avoid using a global. The above will work reliably provided that:

1. the callback order is retained;
2. do not write to the entry in or between the two callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for acquiring the GtkEntry's text is weird. You don't need to play with buffers at all; just do

```
const char *text = gtk_entry_get_text(myEntry);
```

The buffer returned by `text` gives you the complete text, but as a read-only string that is freed when the GtkEntry wants it.

For your needs, you can pass it directly to `gtk_button_set_label()` and `gtk_label_set_text()`:

```
gtk_button_set_label(button, text);
gtk_label_set_text(label, text);
```

And in general, the value stays valid throughout the entire signal handler.

If you want to keep the text around for later, you need to copy it with `g_strdup()` (free with `g_free()`).

Also `gtk_label_set_text()` does not work with GtkEntry; you need to use a GtkLabel with it.